# Emgucv doesn't release resource

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV 3.4.3.3016 to grab frame from camera. Below is the code for simply grab a frame everytime `button1` is clicked. My problem is that the program doesn't release resource so memory used for the program is increasing very fast (up to GBs) and lead to program not responding and then crash.

[image]

Anyone knows the reason and solution?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cap != null)
    {
         cap = new VideoCapture(0);
    }

    Mat img = new Mat();
    cap.Grab();
    cap.Retrieve(img);
    pictureBox1.Image = img.Bitmap;
}
```

Comment: how will it release when you are not calling cap.Dispose()

Comment: @user8190410 Thanks, but `cap.Dispose()` doesn't solve my problem. The reason I put `cap.Retrieve(img)` in a button event is that I want to check how the merory increase every time it grab a frame. In fact, it will run continuously so it's not a good idea to `cap.Dispose()` and then declare `cap = new VideoCapture(0)` all the time. And I also add `cap.Dispose()` but it didn't work too.

Comment: make `Mat img` a class variable. Maybe creating Mat each time you grab a frame is causing this problem

Comment: Making `Mat img` a class variable didn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can run your code normally. Do you have any other dependency? Which is your machine's window version, 32 or 64 bit? Try to debug it in the correct platform, `Debug -> [your-project] Properties -> Build -> Platform target`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem like you before. It's not because of your code or the EmguCV, but it related to debugging setting of your solution. Try removing checking at the `Tools>Options>Debugging>Suppress JIT optimization on module load`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, EmguCV is just the wrapper of OpenCV, we need to clean it up manually by using `GC.Collect()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cap != null) //Why... Are you sure? Not cap==null ???
            {
                cap.Dispose();
                cap = new VideoCapture(0);
            }


            Mat img = new Mat();
            cap.Grab();
            cap.Retrieve(img);
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                var tempImage = pictureBox1.Image;
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
                tempImage.Dispose();

            }
            pictureBox1.Image =new Bitmap( img.Bitmap);
            img.Dispose();
        }
```